# How to set Min and Max value dynamically?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Im using this link https://github.com/Jay-Goo/RangeSeekBar. Import this rangeseekbar module .how to set min and maximum value programatically.

Here java code,

```
        seekbar1.setOnRangeChangedListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChanged(RangeSeekBar view, float min, float max, boolean isFromUser) {
            seekbar1.setProgressDescription((int)min+Sdistance_meter);

            int intvalue = (int)Math.round(min);
            System.out.println("*********venki****driverradius***"+intvalue);
            String mytext=String.valueOf(intvalue);

            Tv_res.setText(mytext+Sdistance_meter);


        }
    });
```

json response,

```
 {
"status": "1",
"response": {
    "min_value": "1000",
    "max_value": "5000",
    "coverage_distance": "100",
    "distance_meter": "m",
    "text": "Area distance coverage by given the value"
}
 }
```

I need to set min_value and max_value in my rangeseekbar.

Answer (score 2):

In the source of the library .

```
public void setRange(float min, float max) {
    setRules(min, max, reserveCount, cellsCount);
}
```

So you can use `seekbar1.setRange(min_value,max_value);`

**1.if you use `app:seekBarMode="single"`**

xml

```
<com.jaygoo.widget.RangeSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:markTextArray="@array/markArray"
    app:lineColorSelected="@color/colorAccent"
    app:thumbResId="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
    app:lineColorEdge="@color/colorSeekBarDefault"
    app:cellMode="number"
    app:seekBarMode="single"/>
```

java

```
seekbar1 = (RangeSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar1);
    seekbar1.setRange(1000.0f, 5000.0f);

    seekbar1.setOnRangeChangedListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChanged(RangeSeekBar view, float min, float max, boolean isFromUser) {
            seekbar1.setProgressDescription((int) min + "%");
        }
});
```

**2.if you use `app:seekBarMode="range"`**

remove `app:progressHintMode="alwaysShow"` and `app:min="-1" app:max="1"` in the xml code .

```
<com.jaygoo.widget.RangeSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:markTextArray="@array/markArray2"
    app:lineColorSelected="@color/colorAccent"
    app:lineColorEdge="@color/colorSeekBarDefault"
    app:textPadding="17dp"
    app:thumbPrimaryColor="@color/colorSeekBarDefault"
    app:thumbSecondaryColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:seekBarHeight="4dp"
    app:thumbSize="20dp"
    app:cellMode="number"
    app:seekBarMode="range"/>
```

java

```
seekbar2 = (RangeSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar2);
    seekbar2.setRange(1000.0f, 5000.0f);

    seekbar2.setOnRangeChangedListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChanged(RangeSeekBar view, float min, float max, boolean isFromUser) {
            seekbar2.setLeftProgressDescription((int) min + "");
            seekbar2.setRightProgressDescription((int) max + "");
        }
  });
```

Comment: this is not working for me. because in that library   mMin = t.getFloat(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_min, 1000);
 mMax = t.getFloat(R.styleable.RangeSeekBar_max, 5000); So whatever we set here this only will reflect.

Comment: And which `seekBarMode` do you use ?

Comment: You can check it.@newone